# Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.CodeQuality;assembly=TfsBuildExtensions.Activities.StyleCop}StyleCop'

Tags: asp.net, database, build

I've imported the DB to the Visual Studio 2012 Team Foundation Server. I've got this error message during the deployment.

TF215097:An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For us, a similar problem was resolved by updating the TfsBuildExtensions (DLLs) to a newer version.
Just download a new version of the files from codeplex.

Our problem was also "unknown type TfsBuildExtensions.Activities..."